# How to schedule a task for batch file which copies big size files to a shared folder?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

main batch file (main.bat):

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Backup process started.

set TARGET_FILES=\\pc1\folder1\*.mdb
ECHO TARGET_FILES "%TARGET_FILES%"

SET DESTINATION_FOLDER=\\pc2\folder1\Backups
ECHO DESTINATION_FOLDER "%DESTINATION_FOLDER%"

SET BACKUP_FOLDER=Backup%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%
ECHO BACKUP_FOLDER "%BACKUP_FOLDER%"

SET FINAL_FOLDER=%DESTINATION_FOLDER%\%BACKUP_FOLDER%
ECHO DIRECTORY CREATED "%FINAL_FOLDER%"

XCOPY "%TARGET_FILES%" "%FINAL_FOLDER%"

ECHO Backup process ended successfully.

@ECHO ON
```

batch file to execute and log main.bat (execute.bat):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET DESTINATION_FOLDER=\\pc2\folder1\Backups
ECHO DESTINATION_FOLDER "%DESTINATION_FOLDER%"

SET BACKUP_FOLDER=Backup%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%
ECHO BACKUP_FOLDER "%BACKUP_FOLDER%"

SET FINAL_FOLDER=%DESTINATION_FOLDER%\%BACKUP_FOLDER%
MKDIR "%FINAL_FOLDER%"
ECHO DIRECTORY CREATED "%FINAL_FOLDER%"

SET LOG_FILE=%FINAL_FOLDER%\%BACKUP_FOLDER%.log
ECHO LOG_FILE "%LOG_FILE%"

main.bat >> "%LOG_FILE%"
@ECHO ON
```

I have set properly the Scheduled Task.
I test it by executing it manually (Right click -> Run).
It executes the task but the mdb files are not copied and backup folder is not created.
**I tried to change TARGET_FILES from `*.mdb` to `*.txt`, it executes as expected.**

The only difference of mdb and txt files are the size. mdb files have 500MB each while txt files have 2KB each.

Any guidance on the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by mapping the two shared folder to a specific drive then use it instead of full path in the batch file.